# Создание файла если его нет

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, fs

Помогите мне с этим. Как мне сделать чтобы при чтении файла он проверял если и он, если нету то создавал с определённым содержимым. Например бот читает ini файл и выводит в консоль, но если его нету в папке, то он его создаёт допустим с параметром power = 1 и выводит в консоль. Потратил на поиски уже весь день. Буду благодарен за помощь !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если блокирующие вызовы подходят, можно так:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const path = 'test.txt';

if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
  fs.writeFileSync(path, '42', 'utf8');
}

console.log(fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8'));
```

Если нужны неблокирующие, для проверки можно использовать, например, [`fs.access()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback).

Comment: А допустим возможно сделать так, если нет этого файла, то он возьмёт данные из другого и запишет в этот файл ?

Comment: Почему нет. `fs.writeFileSync(path, fs.readFileSync('test2.txt', 'utf8'), 'utf8');`

Comment: а есть возможность сделать это через if
Допустим var path = fs.readFileSync(`text1.txt`, 'utf-8');
if(!path) return path fs.readFileSync(`text2.txt`, 'utf-8');
?

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю. В вашем примере просто возвращаются данные из разных файлов, а не создаётся один файл из другого при отсутствии. Возможно, вам лучше переформулировать исходный вопрос с точным указанием, что требуется.